# SELECT a FROM T + Select b from T, or SELECT a,b FROM T? H2 Database

Tags: sql, database, h2, sqlperformance

Which one is faster using the H2 database?

```
SELECT a FROM T 
 and after 
Select b from T
```

or

```
SELECT a,b FROM T
```

Comment: The first one is not a valid SQL Statement

Comment: I mean to do both consecutive

Comment: With no `WHERE` clause in any of these queries?

Comment: Does it matter if have WHERE clauses or not? If so, its the same where clauses on both, based on a 3rd element, like WHERE c == id...

Comment: The general rule for relational DBMSs: one query with a lot of rows is usually faster than a lot of queries with just a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the typical SQL answer: IT DEPENDS :)

I don't know much about H2, but how is your data indexed and distributed?  What are the data types for a and b (is one wide and one narrow)?  Is the client application on the same hardware as your database, or is there network latency involved?  Do you always need to fetch a and b, or is a or b relatively static data that can be cached?

In short, I'm not sure that you can come up with a general rule of thumb that works in all situations; I tend to lean toward the latter (SELECT a,b FROM table), but you're going to have to test and see.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second one, for this Query

```
SELECT a,b FROM T
```

In first query DB engine has to get data from Table 2 times and are been joined together.
So the efficient.

Comment: What if the table is extremely wide but there are narrow indexes on both `a` and `b` individually?